# What is the name of that color test in video production with the beep?

Tags: video

What is the name of those colour test screens at the beginning of videos? I've used it before in Final Cut Pro but I forget what it's called.

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Never mind. Found the answer. It's called "Color Bars".

To be precise...

```
SMPTE Color Bars
SMPTE Bars are "split field" bars composed of:
**Frame Height (Approx)**       **Type of Bars**
Top 67%                     Standard EIA 75% amplitude white bars
Next 8%                     Reverse blue bars
Lower 25%                       Pluge signal
```

[image]
<sub>[source](http://www.mediacollege.com/video/test-patterns/colour-bars-smpte.html)</sub>

Answer (score 0):

**bipbop Test Video**

[https://devstreaming-cdn.apple.com/videos/streaming/examples/bipbop_adv_example_hevc/master.m3u8[enter](https://devstreaming-cdn.apple.com/videos/streaming/examples/bipbop_adv_example_hevc/master.m3u8%5Benter) link description here][1](https://devstreaming-cdn.apple.com/videos/streaming/examples/bipbop_adv_example_hevc/master.m3u8)

For more info check https://developer.apple.com/streaming/examples/

Answer (score 0):

Also sometimes called a test card (famously the BBC one had a kid with a clown where the X on the board was approximately the centre of the screen)

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test_Card_F

[image]